# error:assigning to an array from an initializer list c++

Tags: c++, arrays, error-handling, variable-declaration

I have declared a global multidimensional array `int possw[8][2]`
then I called a function to make changes to it by using another array which I initialized `int w[2]`

```
possw[8][2] = {{b[0]+1,b[1]+2},{b[0]+2,b[1]+1},{b[0]+2,b[1]-1},{b[0]+1,b[1]-2},{b[0]-1,b[1]-2},{b[0]-2,b[1]-1},{b[0]-2,b[1]+1},{b[0]-2,b[1]+2}};
```

Later after reading some StackOverflow posts, I realized I have to use `possw[][]` but that too gave me an error.

```
error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign to an array, only copy to it.

One possible solution here is to make another array, say e.g. `new_passw` that you *initialize*:

```
int new_passw[8][2] = {{b[0]+1,b[1]+2}, ... }};
```

Then you copy from this `new_passw` array into the old `passw` array.